# How is it possible for a Linux Redhat server to run both IIS and Apache on port 80?

Tags: linux, port

I recently got an assignment of pen-testing a remote server. Upon Information Gathering I got the following:

```
 host1 ip 132.56.34.23 port 80 IIS 7.0
 host2 ip 132.56.34.23 port 80 IIS 7.0
 host3 ip 132.56.34.23 port 80 Apache 2.4.6 php 5.4
 host4 ip 132.56.34.23 port 80 Apache 2.4.6 php 7.2
```

Is it possible that 3 of the above are a diversion or it's actually happening? I mean, I understand that a machine can *host* more than one site but not all on port `80` plus a different PHP version.

Comment: Could it be that ip 132.56.34.23 is a load balancer? which means that there could be more than one server behind that address...

Comment: The host may be running a reverse proxy and is the  public front-end with specific sites / applications hosted on different back-end servers, or it randomizes the headers it sends.

Comment: @HBruijn no it does not randomize the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- That is a load balancer or proxy in front of many different web servers.
- The pen testers identification methodology is inaccurate.
- Server header is being spoofed.

If your organization controls this host, determine what it is. Find its owner or access it yourself.

Comment: host3 is using the correct information and also they are 4 domains hosted on apache server, which means indeed it might be a proxy for host1,host2 and host3